# CompileError: Begins at CSS selector undefined

Tags: css, vercel

I am *trying* to host my React project using Vercel. But I encountered an issue and this is the first time I have seen this issue! The project is hosted in Github and the error I get is:

> Failed to compile. 
> Cannot read property 'type' of undefined 
> CompileError: Begins at CSS selector undefined

[image]

**Edit:** 
After some debugging, I found that the issue is with this piece of code:

`Item.css`:

```
@keyframes item__overlay_hide {
from {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0turn);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate3d(2, -1, -1, -0.2turn);
    background-color: rgb(50, 155, 50);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes item__overlay_show {
  from {
    transform: rotate3d(2, -1, -1, -0.2turn);
    background-color: rgb(50, 155, 50);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate3d(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated ! 
Thanks !

Comment: Delete lines from your CSS files until the error stops happening. Then you know which part causes the problem.

Comment: Good to see that you were able to figure it out, I wouldn't have thought that this might be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is stumbling to this issue: 
I just replaced the `turn` to `deg`: 
From:

```
@keyframes item__overlay_hide {
from {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0turn);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate3d(2, -1, -1, -0.2turn);
    background-color: rgb(50, 155, 50);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes item__overlay_show {
  from {
    transform: rotate3d(2, -1, -1, -0.2turn);
    background-color: rgb(50, 155, 50);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate3d(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

to:

```
@keyframes item__overlay_hide {
 from {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate3d(2, -1, -1, -72deg);
    background-color: rgb(50, 155, 50);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes item__overlay_show {
  from {
    transform: rotate3d(2, -1, -1, -72deg);
    background-color: rgb(50, 155, 50);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```